# I am not able to find button click even method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am creating a Xamarin page.
I have some controls like label and buttons. That is below:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Date and Time Picker"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="datepicker1" MaximumDate="2/2/2012"  MinimumDate="1/1/2002"></DatePicker>
    <Button x:Uid="btntime" Text="submit" Clicked="mybtn"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

In the button, I am not able to open click event. How can I redirect the button click event?

Comment: In the page you should find a method called `mybtn`. The `Clicked` attribute in the button declaration specifies the name of the event handler for the `Clicked` event.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly
but if you want the function to appear in the code behind go in you xaml, select the Clicked function and hit "F12" it will create it in the code-behind

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't generate automatically in new version. You have to write it manually in .cs file.

```
 public void mybtn(Object obj, EventArgs args)
    { // your code }
```